# When Is Authentication Challenge Trigger executed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, lambda, triggers, amazon-cognito

As `Auth Challenge` for my User Pool I defined a Lambda Function. This function sends a request to Authy to requiere One Touch Authentication.

I would like to have this setup to add Authy Multi-Factor Authentication to the Cognito Login Process.

**However when I authenticate, login a Cognito User with username and passwort this lambda function is not triggered!**

What do I wrong? Are the Lambda Triggers only for defined for the Register Process? Thanks

---------------------Update:------------------------------------------------

My login code, that requires username and password:

```
authenticate(userName, userPassword) {
    var userData = {Username: userName, Pool : CognitoUserPool}
    var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

    var authenticationData = {Username : userName, Password : userPassword};
    var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (session) {
            AWSInitialize(cognitoUser, session);
            face.showHome();
        }.bind(this),

        mfaRequired: function(session){
            new MFAConfirmation(cognitoUser, 'login');
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Where the Trigger is defined:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean auth challenge? A new custom auth stage for the user authentication? Can you show how you're invoking it/authenticating the user?

Comment: @JeffBailey please see my Update, does this help you to understand my question? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Define Auth Challenge lambda works only in the context of the CUSTOM_AUTH flow so you would have to pass CUSTOM_AUTH as the AuthFlow when authenticating. In Javascript you can do:

```
    cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType('CUSTOM_AUTH');
```

The examples in the Cognito Working with AWS Lambda Triggers developer guide actually do that. They let you define another challenge after authenticating with username and password.

The Define Auth Challenge example lets you setup another challenge after authenticating with username and password. It invokes the Create Auth Challenge lambda trigger when you specify CUSTOM_CHALLENGE as the challenge.

```
    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
        if (event.request.session.length == 1 &&   event.request.session[0].challengeName == 'SRP_A') {
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
            event.response.challengeName = 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER';
        } else if (event.request.session.length == 2 &&       event.request.session[1].challengeName == 'PASSWORD_VERIFIER' && event.request.session[1].challengeResult == true) {
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
            event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
        } else if (event.request.session.length == 3 &&      event.request.session[2].challengeName == 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' && event.request.session[2].challengeResult == true) {
            event.response.issueTokens = true;
            event.response.failAuthentication = false;
        } else {
            event.response.issueTokens = false;
            event.response.failAuthentication = true;
        }
        context.done(null, event);
    }
```

Comment: Dear @IonutTrestian thanks for your answer. The `setAuthenticationFlowType('CUSTOM_AUTH')` statement was missing in my code. It works now perfectly, I was able to develop a Multi-Factor Authentication with Authy. For other interested developers, I will show my set-up on Github. Have a great day!

Comment: Awesome! I'm curious about the setup, can you link me to it when you post it on github?